# Explicit lifetime annotations toy example

Tags: rust, annotations, lifetime

I'm trying to figure out a Rust lifetime issue and after boiling it down a bunch, I realized that I have no idea how I would explicitly annotate the lifetimes of `r`, `x2`, and `_arr` in `foo`:

```
struct X<'a> {
    _v: &'a mut i32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut v1 = 0;
    let x1 = X { _v: &mut v1 };
    foo(x1);
}

fn foo(x1: X) {
    let mut v2 = 1;
    let r = &mut v2;
    let x2 = X { _v: r };
    let _arr = [x1, x2];
}
```

Comment: Looks like your code got cut off. Can you paste the full code, and possibly a Rust playground link?

Comment: that's weird. I can see the struct definition on my end (i.e. from my PoV nothing seems cut off) but apparently others can't?!

Comment: Someone else edited your question to guess the missing part, looks like they guessed right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to work off of the assumption that the part of your code that got cut off is the following:

```rs
struct X<'a> {
    _v: &'a mut i32,
}
```

In that case, let's dissect what's going on in `foo` a little bit.

```rs
fn foo(x1: X) {
    // Lives until the end of the function, call its lifetime 'v2
    let mut v2 = 1;
    // Borrow v2 for some lifetime 'r which is no longer than 'v2
    // so r is of type &'r mut i32
    let r = &mut v2;
    let x2 = X { _v: r }; // x2 is of type X<'r>
    let _arr = [x1, x2]; // ??
}
```

The confusion probably comes from the fact that `x1` seems to have an ambiguous lifetime in its type. This is because we didn't explicitly specify the lifetime in `x1: X`. This is a Rust 2018 idiom, and I personally recommend not doing this. You can add `#![deny(rust_2018_idioms)]` to the top of your crate root and the compiler will point out these ambiguities to you and force you to be more explicit. What happens here is that the function declaration gets de-sugared to the following:

```rs
fn foo<'x1>(x1: X<'x1>) { ... }
```

Now it is implied that the lifetime `'x1` extends at least through the body of `foo`, and this makes sense because it kind of has to. If something which lived for `'x1` was freed in the middle of `foo` (disregarding how something like that could even happen), then that would defeat the point of using lifetimes for memory safety.

So that being said, let's revisit this line:

```rs
let _arr = [x1, x2];
```

We know that `x2` is of the type `X<'r>` and that `'r` extends at most to the end of `foo` (since `'r` is no longer than `'v2` and `'v2` extends to the end of `foo`). Moreover, we know that `x1` is of the type `X<'x1>` and that `'x1` extends at least to the end of `foo`. This means that `'x1` is at least as long as `'r`. Since lifetimes are covariant, this means that `X<'x1>` is a sub-type of `X<'r>`, since whenever we require a value of the type `X<'r>` we can safely substitute in one of type `X<'x1>` instead. So what happens is `_arr` is given the type `[X<'r>; 2]`, and upon construction the lifetime on `x1` is shortened to `'r`.

We can actually test this hypothesis to see if it's correct. What would happen if the compiler wasn't allowed to shorten that lifetime? In other words, what if the lifetime on `X` was not covariant. If we modify `X` as follows then its lifetime type parameter is made invariant:

```rs
struct X<'a> {
    _v: &'a mut i32,
    _invariant: PhantomData<fn(&'a ()) -> &'a ()>
}
```

And sure enough, after adding the `_invariant` field in the appropriate places to make the code compile, we receive the following error:

```rs
   |
14 | fn foo<'x1>(x1: X<'x1>) {
   |        --- lifetime `'x1` defined here
15 |     let mut v2 = 1;
16 |     let r = &mut v2;
   |             ^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
17 |     let x2 = X { _v: r, _invariant: PhantomData };
   |                      - this usage requires that `v2` is borrowed for `'x1`
18 |     let _arr = [x1, x2];
19 | }
   | - `v2` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Now how do we know the compiler wasn't extending the lifetime `'r` to `'x1` in the first place? Well if it was doing that, then we could modify `foo` to do the following, which would unequivocally cause a use-after-free:

```rs
fn foo<'x1>(x1: X<'x1>) -> &'x1 mut i32 {
    let mut v2 = 1;
    let r = &mut v2;
    let x2 = X { _v: r };
    let _arr = [x1, x2];
    _arr[1]._v
}
```

And sure enough if you try the code above it fails to compile with the reason given being that we're returning a reference to a local variable. Moreover, if you try returning `_arr[0]._v`, then you get the exact same error.

Sub-typing and variance can be pretty hard to grasp and it's not something you need to fully understand to be an effective Rust programmer. Nonetheless, it is very interesting and you can learn more about it [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html) in the Rustonomicon.